# Headless bootup diagnostic to see why no network

Tags: networking, boot, ethernet

I've got the latest hardware (rpi 3b+) and am trying to get a flavor ([ev3dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/getting-started/)) to run on it.  However, it never connects to the network - either ethernet or wifi.

I looked into how I could capture the startup logs, and **bootlogd** seemed like what I needed.  However, I'm unsure how to set that up, if I can't connect to the pi to set it up, very much a catch-22.

Is there any way to modify the image after flashing, like how I can add the wifi config file manually via the flashed card's OSX mounted image?  Could I drop off a precompiled bootlogd in the right folder that would get picked up *before bootup* so I capture whatever is failing with the networking?

Or is there already a log file I could load from the SD card?

I hope it isn't an incompatibility - the ev3dev build is from before the 3B **plus** was released, but AFAIK nothing major changed in the network layer, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the ev3dev build is from before the 3B plus was released

The Pi3B+ has new networking hardware and requires new firmware, so is unlikely to work with an old OS.

If this is based on Raspbian, you could try updating on an older model Pi or you could try downloading firmware from http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/ or https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware - you will also need Device Tree for the Pi3B+  bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb

You could try copying from Raspbian, but I would avoid the latest updates with the 4.19 kernel

Comment: I wonder if there is a package, that can be installed on raspbian. Many of these OSs are just a standard OS with one or two custom packages.

Comment: Dang it, I gave away my rpi2.  :(

Comment: I like the idea of clobbering files from the hexxxeh github, thank you!

Comment: I got it partially working (eth but no wifi). I was able to trade my 3b+ for a 3b, so I'm solved.  Future 3b+  users beware!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using Raspbian on the PI.

If you want to write the files from a Gnu/Linux machine, then it is easy. From other OS you have a few choices.

## Option 1

Look up how to write to ext file-system from your OS.

## Option 2

1. Install Virtual-box (this may work with other virtualisation programs, don't try to run more than one at a time, as they will incompatibly try to access virtualisation hardware).
2. Install Debian Gnu/Linux into virtual-box.
3. Insert SD-card into a **USB** SD-card reader/writer.
4. Tell Virtual-box to pass control of this USB device to the guest OS (Debian Gnu/Linux). (Filters in USB settings).
5. Boot the guest OS.
6. Mount the SD-card in Debian.
7. Make the changes.